# ExtJs Menu Binding from database

Tags: extjs

Please provide some sample code or idea about , How to bind menu dynamically from Json results
I get results from database as json ,so how to bind menu from json (Parent and childs)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy actually. When you return the data from the server all you need to do is include a metaData field in your JSON that defines the record structure.

See this documentation:  http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader

The example from the docs is as follows:

```
{

    metaData: {
        "idProperty": "id",
        "root": "rows",
        "totalProperty": "results"
        "successProperty": "success",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "name"},
            {"name": "job", "mapping": "occupation"}
        ],
        // used by store to set its sortInfo
        "sortInfo":{
           "field": "name",
           "direction": "ASC"
        },
        // paging data (if applicable)
        "start": 0,
        "limit": 2,
        // custom property
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    // Reader's configured successProperty
    "success": true,
    // Reader's configured totalProperty
    "results": 2000,
    // Reader's configured root
    // (this data simulates 2 results per page)
    "rows": [ // *Note: this must be an Array
        { "id": 1, "name": "Bill", "occupation": "Gardener" },
        { "id": 2, "name":  "Ben", "occupation": "Horticulturalist" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay,,,,could you please provide sample if possible. Thanks

Comment: It depends on the structure of your data. You can access the raw data via the jsonData property of the JSON reader. And probably loop through the elements to build an array of Ext.menu.Item that you can then use as the items parameter of your menu